# Time complexity of non-recursive algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computer-science, expected-value

I need to calculate an average time complexity. I can assume that random's return value is uniformly distributed.

[image]

Line `6` has $2$ multiplications, line `8` has $1$ multiplication.

$$T_{avg}(n) = ??$$

The propability that condition in line `5` is satisfied is: $p(n) = \frac{n-1}{n^2} \quad \land n > 1$. Here is quick pseudo-proof:

For $n = 2$ two random function calls will return one of these: $11, 12, 21, 22$ so in total $2^2$ results. Only $11$ is valid one because only that satisfies `x1 + x2 = n` condition. So $\frac{1}{4} = \frac{n-1}{n^2}$

For $n = 3$ two random function calls will return one of these: $11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33$ so in total $3^2$ results. Only $12, 21$ are valid. So $\frac{2}{9} = \frac{n-1}{n^2}$.

I know that my proof is not perfect, but it works, improving that proof is not relevant for me.

---

So the propability of executing `6th` line is $p_{if}(n) = \frac{n-1}{n^2}$. Therefore propability of executing `8th` line is $p_{else}(n) = 1 - p_{if}(n) = 1 - \frac{n-1}{n^2}$.

$$T_{avg}(n) = \underbrace{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\frac{n-1}{n^2}2}_{\text{instruction 6}} + \overbrace{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\Bigg(\Big( 1 - \frac{n-1}{n^2}\Big)1\Bigg)}^{\text{instruction 8}}$$

I think I can continue from here. Just not sure if my calculations are correct.

Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't you just say that the average number of multiplications is given by $2\cdot\frac{n-1}{n^2}+1\cdot\left(1-\frac{n-1}{n^2}\right)?$

Comment: Did you forget the sum symbols? After solving the sums I got $T_{avg}(n) = n - \frac{1}{n} + 1$ as a result.

Comment: I didn't "forget" the sum symbols: I don't see the need for them in the first place. I think it matters whether $n$ as the input to the `rand_int` function is simply given and fixed for the entire problem, or not. My impression from the problem statement is that you're simply calling the `rand_int` function over and over again with the same $n$ each time, and then you ask what the average number of multiplications per function call is. In that case, I see no need to do any sums, it's just a straight expectation value calculation.

Comment: @weno: Adrian is correct. What is the $k$ in your sum supposed to represent? As Adrian said in roughly $\frac1n$ number of cases you have 2 multiplications, in the rremaining ones 1 multiplication. You weight $1$ and $2$ with those probabilities and get the result. Nothing in your description indicates that you need to do this for some $k$ variyng from $1$ to $n$.

Comment: @AdrianKeister: Thanks. Feel free to answer in a post so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $n-1$ chances to obtain the sum $n$ (by $1+(n-1),2+(n-2),\cdots(n-1)+1$) on a total of $n^2$.

Hence the average number of multiplications is

$$1+\frac{n-1}{n^2}.$$

---

If the generator wasn't uniform, the value would be

$$1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}p_kp_{n-k}.$$

Answer (score 2):

The average number of multiplications is given by 
$$2\cdot\frac{n-1}{n^2}+1\cdot\left(1-\frac{n-1}{n^2}\right).$$
I don't see the need for the sums that you have; I think it matters whether $n$ as the input to the `rand_int` function is simply given and fixed for the entire problem, or not. My impression from the problem statement is that you're simply calling the `rand_int` function over and over again with the same $n$ each time, and then you ask what the average number of multiplications per function call is. In that case, I see no need to do any sums, it's just a straight expectation value calculation.